# Not signed in Earth Enine or Project is not Registered

Tags: python, authentication, google-earth-engine

Hi I am attempting to use the Python API to access google earth engine from VsCode.

When I enter,

```
import ee 
ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()
```

I get the following error for `ee.Initialize()` step - "ee.ee_exception.EEException: Not signed up for Earth Engine or project is not registered. Visit [https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/access"](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/access%22)

Prior to that the `ee.Authenticate()` step works fine where a new web page opens up stating "You are now authenticated with the gcloud CLI!"

I also have existing google earth engine cloud project called "ee-imantha".

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem. I configured `FastAPI` service with `GEE` and after several tries i did it.

Solution

1. You need to sing in `gcloud` (You need to install `gcloud` in your local host, if you are windows user, simplest way by scoop.sh) in you local machine
2. Select project(it's important), because when i chose different
   project, it didn't work because my service account was connected
   another cloud project
3. Create service account with permission to `GEE`
4. Create private key for service account
5. Write below code

```py
service_account = 'my-earth@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
credentials = ee.ServiceAccountCredentials(service_account, './my-project-1111cceb213b.json')
ee.Initialize(credentials)
```

it work for me

p.s
`ee.Authenticate()` - not good way to implement your service, it's useful only for testing

reference:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/service_account#use-a-service-account-with-a-private-key